Next.js Hydration Error : Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <main> in <div>
i am facing issue of hydration in my next.js application. while alot of trubleshooting i come to a result that , it might be because of the higher order component which is withAutch.js
the error says: Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

Mentor dashboard
import BarChart from "@/components/mentor/chart/bar-chart/page";
import LineChart from "@/components/mentor/chart/line-chart/page";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import "./page.scss";
import StdTable from "@/components/mentor/student-table/page";
import HowItWorksSection from "@/components/mentor/how-it-works/page";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const MentorDash = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.data.user);

  return (
    <main className="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 p-mb p-0 mentor-profile">
      <div className="bg-screen position-relative">
        <div className="row py-4">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <h1 className="text-white">Welcome Back, {user.first_name} {user.last_name}.</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row g-3 py-3">
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-3  ">
            <div className="p-3 bg-white rounded justify-content-between d-flex">
              <span>
                <p className="dashboard-p-label">Students</p>
                <h3>342</h3>
              </span>
              <Image src="/mentor-home/std.svg" height={60} width={60} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-3  ">
            <div className="p-3 bg-white rounded d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span>
                <p className="dashboard-p-label">Awards</p>
                <h3>30+</h3>
              </span>
              <Image src="/mentor-home/award.svg" height={60} width={60} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div className="p-3 bg-white rounded d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span>
                <p className="dashboard-p-label">Staff</p>
                <h3>312+</h3>
              </span>
              <Image src="/mentor-home/staff.svg" height={60} width={60} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div className="p-3 bg-white rounded d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span>
                <p className="dashboard-p-label">Revenue</p>
                <h3>$34M</h3>
              </span>
              <Image src="/mentor-home/revenue.svg" height={60} width={60} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row g-3 pb-3">
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 rounded">
            <LineChart />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 rounded">
            <BarChart />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row g-1">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <StdTable />
          </div>
        </div>
        <HowItWorksSection />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default MentorDash;

mentor home code
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./page.scss";
import MentorDash from "@/components/mentor/dashboard/page";
import ProfileCompletion from "@/components/mentor/profile/page";
import WithAuth from "@/components/withAuth";

const MentorHome = () => {
  const [displayMentorDash, setDisplayMentorDash] = useState(true);

  const handleSwitchComponent = () => {
    setDisplayMentorDash(!displayMentorDash);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {displayMentorDash ? <MentorDash /> : <ProfileCompletion />}
      <button className="btn btn-lg btn-info" onClick={handleSwitchComponent}>
        Switch Component
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default WithAuth(MentorHome);


Higer order component
"use client";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { logoutUser } from "@/app/Redux/slices/authSlice";

export default function WithAuth(Component) {
  return function WithAuth(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const pathname = usePathname().split("/");
    const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.data.accessToken);
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.data.user);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const logoutTimerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!token) {
        router.push("/");
      }


    useEffect(() => {
      // Redirect logic based on user role and pathname
      if (user == null) {
        router.push("/");
      }
      if (user != null && user.role[0].id == 3 && pathname[1] == "mentor") {
        router.push("/student/home");
      }
      if (user != null && user.role[0].id == 2 && pathname[1] == "student") {
        router.push("/mentor/home");
      }
    }, [pathname, router, user]);

    return token ? <Component {...props} /> : null;
  };
}


i am unable to resolve this issue , can anyone please look into this

Try this: delete .next folder and restart the server. Solves the same issue sometimes. Also i believe that it takes some time to get the token and user data, so you may need a loading indicator to return some loaders before checking the token based on which you return the component

You can use layout to render WithAuth.
This error will occur when the server render html and client render html is different.
I suspect the issue might be with the redirection which you have written in the use effect, If the token is present you are rending the Component and you are checking the role and redirecting, before redirecting the component also rendered.

what could be the other better way to render
